# How to club variables and then make the date into ascending order in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table with two columns;PHONENO(varchar2) and calldate(datetime).I need to get similar phone numbers altogether and then ascending order the calldate within a phone number.This is the SQL query I am using.

```
SELECT PHONENO,CALLDATE
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY PHONENO,CALLDATE
ORDER BY PHONENO asc,CALLDATE
```

Eventhough the CALLDATE is in ascending order Similar PHONENo's are still not togetger.Why I am not getting Similar phone numbers together and calldate order within it?(Eventhough the PHONENO in varchar2 format it contains 0f 9 integer values)

Comment: GROUP BY, but no aggregate functions - how come?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the output of the query so we can better understand the problem.